# Matcher does not detect difference. Error?

Tags: jasmine

is this a bug? The below test succeeds.

```
describe("Jasmine test", () => {
  it("should report an error", () => {
    expect("//File-1").toMatch("/File-1");
  });
});
```

Comment: `//File-1` definitely matches the regular expression for `/File-1`: https://regex101.com/r/Ca6jfg/1 Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: Thanks you. Actually was not aware that toMatch makes a regex-match

Comment: https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#toMatch